# R, putting a for loop result into a vector and adding this vector to a data frame

Tags: r

I have made a for loop that takes the latency(time) and outputs the total scores seen. (i.e.: Latency=1000, # of scores seen = "one"). I would like to place the results of the for loop into my current data frame, in a new column. So, for example, there would be a column with, "one", "two, "one"..etc.  Could anyone help me?

This is what I have tried so far:

I tried creating a vector from this for loop. I read on other questions that it's better to work with vectors on R.

First, I turned this for loop into a function called "score":

```html
score <- function(i){
  if(i<1000){
    print("one")
  }else if(i<2000){
    print("two")
  } else if (i < 3000){
    print("three")
  } else if (i < 4000){
    print("four")
  }else if (i < 5000){
    print("five")
  }else if(i < 6000){
    print ("six ")
  }else if(i<7000){
    print("seven")
  }else {
    print("other")
  }
}
```

I then used the `lapply` function to apply the `score` function  to my `DDM` dataframe, more specifically  my `Latency` column. I assigned this `lapply` to a vector called `Lat`:

```html
Lat <- lapply(DDM$latency, score)
Lat
```

This is the output for the function, I've only included a few line bc its very long:

```html
[[1]]
[1] "three"

[[2]]
[1] "one"

[[3]]
[1] "two"

[[4]]
[1] "one"

[[5]]
[1] "one"

[[6]]
[1] "one"

[[7]]
[1] "one"

[[8]]
[1] "one"

[[9]]
[1] "one"

[[10]]
[1] "one"

[[11]]
[1] "one"
```

I then added this vector as a column to my data frame.

```html
DDM$Newlat<- c(Lat)
```

But the problem is when I run my dataframe, "DDM", and look at the new column every row shows "<chr [1]>". I think it might be because the output of my for loop are characters.

This is the out put of my new column, `Newlat` if I ran my dataframe:

```html
<chr [1]>
<chr [1]>
<chr [1]>
<chr [1]>
<chr [1]>
<chr [1]>
```

Seeing what I have tried, is there a better way or a way to fix my current code so that there would be a new column with my desired output.

Thank you for your help in advance!!

Comment: Please `dput(DDM)` and add the output to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `print` just prints the values, it does not `return` it. Use `return` if you want to save it.
- You should not do this one by one for each value using `lapply`. There are vectorised ways to achieve this. You can use `ifelse` here to pass the entire vector (`DDM$latency`). A simplified version of nested `ifelse` is `dplyr::case_when`.
- You should actually use `cut`/`findInterval` here instead. Something like :

```
DDM$Newlat <- cut(DDM$latency, c(seq(0, 700, 100), Inf), 
    labels = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'other'))
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say return "saves it"?  I am new to R so an explanation in your answer would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Kim_unistudent replace `print` with `return` in your function. and use `DDM$Newlat <- sapply(DDM$latency, score)`

Comment: Hi, Ronak. Sorry for this late reply but I wanted to thank you for your help. Your advice helped, I got my column looking how I want it to. Thanks again!